# Pydev plugin with eclipse IDE

Tags: python-3.x, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I've installed Pydev plugin with eclipse c/c++ and it worked will but after two days something wrong happened and it shows this message

(No editor descriptor for id org.python.pydev.editor.PythonEditor)

I tried to install it once again but still the same problem

Answer (score 0):

That message means that PyDev isn't really properly installed or its requisites are not properly matched.

The possible reasons are that you're using a different java vm from the one you had (PyDev requires java 8 onwards), it became corrupted (i.e.: could happen if you had some issue in your hard drive, but that's very rare compared with not running Eclipse using java 8) or you're using an older version of Eclipse with a newer version of PyDev (see the "Need to use older Eclipse/Java" section on http://www.pydev.org/download.html).